# read a specific line in the sub folders and calculate average

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm new to Linux scripting. I have folders lets say

```
/movies
/movies/starting_with_a/metric.txt
/movies/starting_with_b/metric.txt
```

Example contents of `metric.txt`:

```
dummy_first_line
actual data = 8
```

I want to read metric.txt in all the sub folders and calculate the average for that folder.

My current code to extract the values is:

```
for i in $(find . -name 'metric.txt');do cat "$i" | sed -n '2p'|awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Let's say I'm guessing that this value will be on 2nd line in each file.

Comment: Put all relevant info in your question, don't spread it out across comments. Make sure to add a [mcve], see [ask]. "folder" is a Windows term, btw - in UNIX there are "directories" and "files".

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. You just needed to feed the output of your command:

```
for i in $(find . -name 'metric.txt');do cat "$i" | sed -n '2p'|awk '{print $NF}'
```

to AWK to compute average:

```
awk '{ sum += $NF; cnt += 1 } END { printf "%.2f\n", sum/cnt }'
```

Here I do it with two AWK commands (no need to do `cat` and `sed`):

```
for i in $(find . -name 'metric.txt'); do
    awk 'NR == 2 { print $NF }' "$i"; 
done  |  awk '{ sum += $NF; cnt += 1 } END { printf "%.2f\n", sum/cnt }'
```